# NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined,But I have executed Test-train split successfully

Tags: python, nameerror

After successfully executing the Test-train split, I continue to execute moding, but a NameError appears. Is there any paragraph that I have not defined clearly?

```
# Test-train split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df.iloc[:,0:5]
y = df['charges']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

print(X_train.shape) #(3500, 5)
print(X_test.shape) #(1500, 5)
print(y_train.shape) #(3500, )
print(y_test.shape) #(1500, )

--------
(936, 5)
(402, 5)
(936,)
(402,)

# Modeling
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

print("The intercept term of the linear model:", reg.intercept_)

print("The coefficients of the linear model:", reg.coef_)

----------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c8fa5d4c8df7> in <cell line: 8>()
---->   reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
        print("The intercept term of the linear model:", reg.intercept_)

NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined
```

I confirmed that the data set df was divided into training set and test set, and I tried to re-execute # Test-train split and it succeeded, but after executing #mod, it was still an error

Comment: It looks like `X_train` was defined in a previous cell, and then you restarted the workbook, and did not re-execute that cell?

Comment: Maybe try combining those cells together?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am using colab, is it wrong to execute the Test-train split block before executing the mod?